# SQL Server Point to polygon issue

Tags: sql-server

So I have a shape file, and this query would work by grabbing a bunch lats and longs

```
DECLARE 
    @GeoUnitBoundaries GEOGRAPHY 
    ,@State char(2)
    ,@GeoUnitControlKey int
    
    
DECLARE contact_cursor CURSOR FOR
 SELECT id, geom
 FROM [GIS].[dbo].[oh_2020_state_upper_2021-09-16_2031-06-30]
 where geom is not null

  
OPEN contact_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor
INTO @geounitboundaries,@GeoUnitControlKey


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


    SELECT 
        @GeoUnitBoundaries = geom
        ,@GeoUnitControlKey = ID  
    FROM [GIS].[dbo].[oh_2020_state_upper_2021-09-16_2031-06-30]
    WHERE ID = @GeoUnitControlKey and geom is not null
    
    
    update   [work_old].[dbo].[oh_jk] 
    set sd_new = @GeoUnitControlKey
    from   [work_old].[dbo].[oh_jk] a
    where geography::STGeomFromText( 'POINT('+RegistrationAddressLongitude+' '+RegistrationAddressLatitude+')',4326 ).STIntersects(@GeoUnitBoundaries) = 1
    and sd_new is null  and RegistrationAddressLongitude <> ' ' and RegistrationAddressLatitude <> ' '

    raiserror(@geounitcontrolkey,0,1) with nowait


   FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor
   INTO @geounitboundaries,@GeoUnitControlKey
END


CLOSE contact_cursor
DEALLOCATE contact_cursor
GO
```

I know my problem is that the shape file data type coming in is geometry

I have to assume their is an easier way to join a column off a shape file file and add it to an existing table based on if the point lies within the shape.  Apologizes in advance, I put this together like 8 years ago.

Comment: It's really unclear what you are trying to achieve, and the reason for using a cursor is unclear also. Sample data and expected output would help immensely

Comment: So think of it this way, I have a shape file that has polygons, which is the OH state senate districts, then I have a voterfile that I geocoded and have lats and longs for, so if Charlieface is in district 9, then I want to add district 9 to his record.  It's all public data that can be downloaded from the OH SOS website.  https://redistricting.lls.edu/state/ohio/?cycle=2020&level=State%20Upper&startdate=2021-09-16

https://www6.ohiosos.gov/ords/f?p=111:1

Comment: I'm not about to download data from some random website and recreate your tables, I'm afraid. You need to add sample data and expected output, either as [so] Markdown Tables, or as `CREATE TABLE` `INSERT` statements. A https://dbfiddle.uk/ would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out it out, easily.  Using `SQLServerSptialTools`  you can do this:

```
SET GEOjk = dbo.MakeValidGeographyFromGeometry(GEOM)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple joined update looks like it should work

```sql
UPDATE jk
SET sd_new = su.ID
from [work_old].[dbo].[oh_jk] jk
JOIN [GIS].[dbo].[oh_2020_state_upper_2021-09-16_2031-06-30] su
WHERE geography::STGeomFromText(
    'POINT(' + RegistrationAddressLongitude + ' ' + RegistrationAddressLatitude + ')',
     4326
  ).STIntersects(
     geography::STGeomFromText(su.geom.STAsText(), 4326)
  ) = 1
  AND jk.sd_new IS NULL
  AND jk.RegistrationAddressLongitude <> ' '
  AND jk.RegistrationAddressLatitude <> ' '
  AND su.geom is not null;
```

For large datasets, it may be more performant to precalculate the `geography` values and create indexes on them.

Comment: I'm not worried about the performance just yet, but I'm assuming the where should be an on  and I still get Operand type clash: geometry is incompatible with geography

Comment: OK given you a solution for that. But really `geom` should be the correct data type in the first place: `geometry` and `geography` are *not* the same thing

Comment: I'm well aware, but MS SQL isn't reading it in correctly even if I use shape2sql, or OGR2OGR

Geometry looks like correct way while converting it to geography it puts the map on it's side